# How to get Total Pupulation From Tables In Sqlserver?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i Have one Table Population

```
Stateid  StateName  Year  Popution

01      xx          2008     200000

02      xy          2008     400000

01      xx          2009     500000

02      xy          2009     900000
```

So need Result each state Total popution in 2009? how to get. any one please suggestion me?

Comment: `select stateid,sum(popution) from table where Year=2009 group by stateid`

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Sum` sql aggregate function. Getting the total population for all rows in 2009:

```
SELECT Sum(Population) FROM Population WHERE Year = 2009
```

If you want to get the total population for each state in 2009, group by the StateName column:

```
SELECT StateName,
       Sum(Population)
FROM   Population
WHERE  Year = 2009
GROUP BY StateName
```

Remove the `Where` condition if you want to see this for all years.

Comment: i need each state popution http://stackoverflow.com/users/51/yaakov-ellis

Comment: No it not  showing aggregate Result http://stackoverflow.com/users/51/yaakov-ellis

Comment: i need result xx:700000,xy:900000

Comment: @user3187760 where would 700000 come from? You have one row in your sample for each year/state combo

Comment: i want add total popution http://stackoverflow.com/users/51/yaakov-ellis

Answer (score 0):

Enter "sql get sum per group of values" into google, check this very first [link here (link)](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/sum-with-group-by.php).

```
SELECT Sum(Population) TotalPopulation, Year, StateName
FROM [Population] 
WHERE Year = 2009 AND StateName = 'ZYX'
GROUP BY Year, StateName
```

Comment: i Need Each state Result at 2009 http://stackoverflow.com/users/1120991/kahn

Comment: So remove the "AND StateName = 'ZYX'", and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

This gives the population of each state in the year 2009 : In your test data in don't see multiple records for the same state for a single year.

```
select [statename],sum([population]) from [population] 
where [year]= 2009 group by [statename];
```

Comment: But hear your query not doing sum. it displays last Record value http://stackoverflow.com/users/2895032/punter015

Comment: @user3187760 It gives the last recorded value only because you have one record for each state for year 2009. In case you have multiple records you will have the sum.